# Array data type memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've been teaching myself how to write in C and I've successfully written a fair sized program. I'm not having issues with compiling or executing the program, but I'm a little concerned with a minor detail regarding memory allocation of array data types.

I dynamically allocate memory to an array in the following manner:

```
double **array=malloc(n*sizeof(*array));
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    array[i]=malloc(3*sizeof(*(array[i])));
}
```

This works perfectly well for constructing a nx3 array and I'm glad for that; however, I've taken in context from a number of previous Q&A's that you are required to free not only the array itself but also each element in the array. Why than, in my case, am I not able to free the elements? When I do this:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    free(array[i]);
}
free(array);
```

the loop causes a memory corruption. When I remove the loop and simply free the array, there is no segmentation fault or corruption and it runs smoothly. Can someone please explain this to me? Am I not understanding the principles of freeing pointers vs. variables in instances like this?

Thanks and best regards,
Mike

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) ... your problem is most likely in code you haven't shown us ... odds are that you've gone beyond the bounds of your allocated memory. Or maybe you use the memory after freeing it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Given that I'm writing this program to analyze academic proprietary data, I'm unable to provide the program. It's also over 1000 lines and I'm sure you wouldn't want to waste time investigating. I'm mainly curious because I haven't freed this memory at all and it sits within a while loop running over thousands of data points before beginning anew at i=0 for many more thousands of points. I'm not seeing why it doesn't seg fault...

Comment: I didn't ask you to provide the program, I asked you to provide an SSCCE, which is somewhat the opposite. "I'm not seeing why it doesn't seg fault..." -- eh?  First, you haven't given any reason why you expect it to segfault; second, segfaulting is never *guaranteed* ... it's easy to have invalid programs that happen not to crash. Corruption of malloced areas often cause a segfault when the memory is freed, not earlier. I suggest that you learn about debuggers and memory corruption detection tools like valgrind.

Comment: I see. Given my amateur knowledge of programming in general, I'll first take your advice and invest time in learning about debugging tools. I'll also work on putting together an SSCCE that inputs dummy data so you'll have something to work with.  My apologies for silly questions!

Comment: No need for apology, especially since your question wasn't silly (it just reflected incorrect assumptions). The takeaway should be that your code snippets above for mallocing and freeing are correct, and that's not (directly) your problem ... it's something else your code is doing that corrupts malloc's bookkeeping and thus causes a segfault when it attempts to free. Be sure that, if you're allocating 3 doubles (for example), your program never tries to store into a fourth ... that would definitely produce this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same idea — based very closely on your code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int n = 20;
    double **array = malloc(n * sizeof(*array));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        array[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(*(array[i])));
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            array[x][y] = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with GCC 4.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.5 and run under [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) 3.10.0, it produces a clean bill of health:

```
==7957== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7957== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7957== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7957== Command: mma
==7957== 
==7957== 
==7957== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7957==     in use at exit: 25,245 bytes in 373 blocks
==7957==   total heap usage: 470 allocs, 97 frees, 31,829 bytes allocated
==7957== 
==7957== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7957==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7957==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7957==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7957==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7957==         suppressed: 25,245 bytes in 373 blocks
==7957== 
==7957== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7957== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

(There's always a lot of memory allocation done by the Mac OS X runtime library.)

That strongly suggests that the problem is not in the memory allocation or deallocation code, but in the code where the memory is (mis)used.